# Chrome Web Store promotional tile Image has been rejected

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have tried (about a dozen times now) to add promotional tiles to my extension's web store listing.

I am getting this one every single time:

"This small tile image has been rejected due to the following reasons:
Text is too small
Too much detail
Please review the guidelines, upload a new image and republish."

I thought for a while that it's about text, but at my last try it was even without a single character in there and it was still rejected. Also I think the text rule is not that enforced since every single one on the front page has it's name on the tile.

Here is the last one I tried (instantly rejected this time so most likely automatic?) https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWThq.png

Another one I tried a few days ago: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyVcq.png

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the gun and use instead a symbol like an aim or whatever works visually for the game.

Comment: Hmm, you think it would be flagged for that? I will try later (I also suspect they don't like to be spammed with requests, but the last one was too quick to be manual)

Comment: To give an update on this, this is one I just tried: https://i.imgur.com/fdyyIsG.png
And it was rejected immediately for the same "text is too small, too much detail" message. I emailed them after creating this question and haven't heard back since. It was over a month ago..

Answer (score 2):

The Chrome Webstore Developer support got back to me with the response
"I've checked your item and your promotional image is now fixed"
So it seems like a bug somewhere in their system so if anyone else runs into this don't do what I did and spend months trying to tweak your promotional images over and over, just contact them..

EDIT: For some reason the Developer Support contact form is extremely hard to find. Here it is: https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support?hl=en
The follow up support emails came from these address: `cws-developer-support@google.com` and `developer-support@google.com`

Comment: Thanks @Gergely. Been having the same issue for weeks and emailed them previously with no response - hopefully the contact form will work...